# Is it possible to open multiple files at the end or at the first occurrence of a string?

Tags: search, multiple-files, startup

To open multiple files at a time I use this command (here using the vi tab feature):

```
vim -p file1 file2 ... fileN
```

If I want to open a file at the end or at the first occurrence of a text:

```
vim + file1 or vim +/searchPattern file1
```

How to combine these 2 operations?

With `vim + file1 file2` it works only for the first file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround would be to use `:argdo` (which runs an ex command in each file in the argument list):

```
vim +"argdo norm G" file1 file2
vim +"argdo /searchPattern" file1 file2
```

You will be left in the final file, so you'll need to manually invoke `:first` to return to the beginning of the arglist, or add this as another command-line argument:

```
vim +"argdo norm G" +first file1 file2
```